# Android bluetooth communication with 2 Activities

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm can send data from the phone to the arduino and get a response in the phone, but just in the same activity, for practical reasons I need to show the data received in the phone in another activity, so I try to pass the received data using the put extras option but I get an error and te aplication crashed, because the data is receiving in other thread I think that that could cause problems if the received data isn't complete before launch the second activity, any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

ok i have done this a really long time ago and i don't remember exactly what changes i made in the bluetooth sample so just follow these steps and you will be sending and receiving strings from any class.

if you are using the bluetooth chat example in android sdk samples, then do the following:

-in the bluetoothchat class:
*change "private" BluetoothChatService mChatService into "public".
then in the activity you want to send a string from do this

```
 BluetoothChat.mChatService.write(byteArray);
```

where byteArray is as it sounds an array of bytes, so you need a a string to byte array converter to make things easy:

```
 public static byte[] convertStringToByteArray(String s)
 {
 byte[] byteArray = null;
 if(s!=null)
 {
 if(s.length()>0)
 {
 try
 {
 byteArray = s.getBytes();
  } catch (Exception e)
 {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
 return byteArray;
 }
```

that's for sending, and as for receiving:

what i did is make a Boolean for entering and exiting a specific class so for example when i enter a class i would make this Boolean true and forward the string i receive in the Bluetoothchat class to the class i want, like for example you will go to the bluetooth chat class at these code lines:

```
    case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
```

where readMessage is the string message you recieve , but instead you will make it "readMessage" a public static variable.....so you would say if i'm in activity for example number one then set the static boolean value to true and you would make a function for example called update which checks if the boolean was true then get the readMessage string and do whatever you want with it , like set text for example:

```
 if(Bluetoothchat.one==true)
 tv.settext(Bluetoothchat.readMessage);
```

then you need to change this boolean to false when you exit the current activity you are in so the application won't crash, so you can do something like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

BluetoothChatone.one=false;
 super.onBackPressed();

   }
```

and if you get errors tell me so i can see what i have missed to tell you.